# How to remove “paypal/express/review” step

Tags: paypal

Can you please provide solution or any module to remove extra layer of review with paypal express checkout method

we are using Magento 1.7.0.0 Version.

Thanks
Chetan

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the best way to accomplish this with Magento in particular, but it is an open source cart so you could conceivably implement the necessary modifications:

- Append "&useraction=commit" when redirecting the customer to PayPal. This will change the button verbiage on PayPal.com from "Continue" to "Pay Now".  It is a cosmetic-only change, it will not make any functional changes.
- The corresponding functional change is to have your server immediately execute the API call DoExpressCheckoutPayment when the customer returns, skipping the review step and directly displaying the result.